# How to find max RAM speed supported

Tags: memory

I'm intending to add some RAM into my current laptop. I have tried and read articles about RAM (memory and speed). I understand that laptop uses specific RAM (SODIMM).

I'm trying to find out what is the maximum speed (MHz) the motherboard is made to handle. I tried to look up the motherboard information and computer model. Yet unable to find an answer.

Can someone please give me some advises or the better the answer.

Fujitsu LH700
Core i5
64-bit windows 7

As far as I know at this point, 64bit can handle 8GB RAM maximum.

Thank you very much

Comment: Its not clear how you expect us to provide you this information if the information on your motherboard isn't available.  You don't even indicate which CPU you have, saying you have an i5, is not specific enough. "As far as I know at this point, 64-bit can handle 8 GB RAM maximum." 64-bit versions of Windows can support a great deal more then 8 GB.

Comment: You should supply more detail. But In general with Laptops it's a good idea to go to the laptop maker website, in your case Fujitsu, hunt the model down in support and refer to the user manual which will normally state the motherboard specifications including RAM obligations

Comment: Ramhound and Harvey, thank you very much for your notes and comments. I'm not too familiar with what information was necessary. I should have written that as a note.

Comment: What other information do you need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It takes a bit of web searching. From your model number, I get this page:
http://www.cnet.com/products/fujitsu-lifebook-ah530-15-6-core-i5-480m-windows-7-home-premium-64-bit-4-gb-ram-500-gb-hdd/specs/

which says you have a 
`Intel Core i5 480M`.

Since you are looking for Intel specs, the only place you want to go is ARK.intel.com:
http://ark.intel.com/products/52952/Intel-Core-i5-480M-Processor-3M-Cache-2_66-GHz

**From here we see the CPU supports DDR3 800/1066, so [1066](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR3_SDRAM#JEDEC_standard_modules) is the MAX.**

Note, x64 can *theoretically* support up to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 Bytes of addressable RAM. Of course no consumer platform actually comes close, but you can find consumer desktops that support 32, 64, or even 128 GB of ram.

Comment: The author actually wants to know the maximum frequency of the memory supported not the maximum amount of memory.

Comment: good point. answer is the same, except the summation. gmas and I'll edit it.

Comment: @FrankThomas Thank you for the explanations and links. It said M520 in the properties and after looking at the intel link, I believe it is Core i5 520M. According to the page, "DDR3 800/1066". I don't understand why there are two speed values, but 1066 is maximum?
[link](http://ark.intel.com/products/47341/Intel-Core-i5-520M-Processor-3M-Cache-2_40-GHz)

Comment: @Maki - Its the native default frequency that the memory will be ran at without memory overclocking, but memory can be overclocked, how much is entirely up to the firmware of your specific hardware.

Comment: @Ramhound hmm, i thought it is unsafe to put a ram with higher MHz than the recommended speed. It could be false information, just being safe.

Comment: @Maki - There are standards that handle the detection and configuration of the memory frequency.

Comment: For the most part, ram will run at the frequency of the SPD, so DDR3 is downward compatible for RAM frequency. eg if you put DDR3 1600Mhz ram in the box, SPD would run it with the JEDEC profile for 1066. Voltage is probably the only spec to be really afraid of, as you can fry the new chips if their voltage spec is well under the motherboards.

Comment: Thank you Frank. Glad you wrote the example. May I ask how to find the correct voltage? I understood there are 2 types, 1.35 and 1.5. 1.5 can't be used in 1.35v motherboard/computer.

Comment: The easiest way is to take out one of the existing chips and examine its labeling, perhaps searching online for the model number if the voltage is not printed on it.

Answer (score -2):

Your laptop model - Fujitsu LifeBook LH700 - supports a max of 8GB RAM, as per the original [Factsheet](http://www.fujitsu.com/downloads/COMP/fpcap/notebooks/previous/LH700_Factsheet.pdf) as well as [crucial](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Fujitsu/lifebook-lh700).

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. OP is asking for "maximum speed (MHz) the motherboard is made to handle." **not** maximum RAM.